# Using variable names as property names in lodash _.findIndex

Tags: lodash

```
var ids = ["John", "Mary", "Joe", "Chase", "Sarah"];

for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
  var id = ids[i];
  var max = 25; // fixed for simplicity
  var maxObj = _.findIndex(people['scores'], { id : max });
}
```

The above does not work as _.findIndex returns -1 for maxObj. However, if i explicitly define the property name as a string (instead of using the id variable), it works.

```
var maxObj = _.findIndex(people['scores'], { "John" : max });
```

Is there a way to pass variable values to the property name in lodash or an alternate way to achieve this using lodash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could construct an object literal using the dynamic key and then feed that to `_.findIndex`:

```
var ids = ["John", "Mary", "Joe", "Chase", "Sarah"];

for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
  var id = ids[i];
  var max = 25; // fixed for simplicity
  var obj = {};
  obj[id] = max;
  var maxObj = _.findIndex(people['scores'], obj);
}
```